# How to hide contents of a named pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have a writer process and a reader process which communicate using a named pipe
 /FIFO/pipeAB which is created with permission 666.

The contents of the pipe can be viewed from bash shell at runtime using

```
cat /FIFO/pipeAB
```

How do I prevent ALL users from viewing the contents of the pipe at runtime using cat or any other tool, without affecting the reader process?

Comment: Since you mention the permissions on the fifo, have you considered changing these? Or changing the permissions on the parent directory?

Comment: @Kusalananda Can you elaborate about changing the permissions of the FIFO? If I remove Read permission for User,Group and Others, the reader process won't be able to read the FIFO.

Comment: Well, your question is _literally_ "how can I prevent all users from reading from the pipe?".  You could remove permissions for everyone but the owner. You may want to clarify your question. Also, if users can't access the directory where the fifo is located (no `x` permissions), they obviously can't access the fifo.